# Excel: Reorienting array while maintaining original data order

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Question**: Based on a supplied *Input_array*, how to reorient (vertical) *Array_1* into (horizontal) *Array_2* without VBA, while maintaining data order (process,val) from *Array_1*?

**Note**: the header rows are not included in the actual operation, just the data (i.e., the sizes of Array_1 and Array_2 are 9x2 and 4*6, respectively)

*Input_array*: {1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3} with each value corresponding to each row in *Array_1*

*Array_1* (initial):

| process | val |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0.4 |
| C | 0.2 |
| D | 1.3 |
| E | 0.6 |
| F | 0.9 |
| G | 1 |
| H | 0 |
| I | 0.2 |

*Array_2* (desired):

| process | val | process | val | process | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | D | 1.3 | H | 0 |
| B | 0.4 | E | 0.6 | I | 0.2 |
| C | 0.2 | F | 0.9 |  |  |
|  | 0.2 | G | 1 |  |  |

**Brute-force solution**: `IFNA(HSTACK(FILTER(Array_1,Input_array=1),FILTER(Array_1,Input_array=2),FILTER(Array_1,Input_array=3),"")`

I'd like a less verbose dynamic solution that would accommodate changes in Input_array.

Comment: In case of input array `{1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3}`, can you make like `{3,4,2}`?

Comment: Input_array size corresponds to number of (process,val) pairs in arrays 1 and 2. Truncating/processing the Input_array to a smaller size is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This formula will give you the desired result.

```
=LET(i,D2:D10,
IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(i),LAMBDA(r,x,HSTACK(r,FILTER(Tabelle2,x=i),""))),,1),""))
```

In this case REDUCE does the HSTACK job per row in your input array.

[image]

Comment: That is about 3X shorter than my effort! I suppose if I'm being really picky there could be a situation where the unique removed one of the columns, but otherwise brilliant.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! How would you add a blank column between each (process,val) pair (e.g., output array's first row would then be {A,1,"",D,1.1,"",H,0,""} etc.)?

Comment: Yeah I did that and ran into trouble with missing columns just like Tom Sharpe alluded. Is it possible to make this one robust to UNIQUE() skipping duplicate columns (e.g., the blank ones or actual values)?

Comment: OK - fixed the missing column issue plus empty column

Comment: If there are duplicate columns that should be in the output array. For instance if Array_1 was {A,1;B,2;C,3;D,1;E,2;F,3;G,1;H,1;I,1} and Input_array was {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3}. Array_2 would then erroneously be {A,1,D,G,1;B,2,E,H,1;C,3,F,I,1} even though it should be {A,1,D,1,G,1;B,2,E,2,H,1;C,3,F,3,I,1} as the column values of 'ABC' are duplicates of 'DEF'.

Comment: can you check with the new version - I think this should work now.

Answer (score 1):

No sure if this is worth posting as it's so long but anyway you could use makearay like this:

```
=LET(Array_1,A2:B10,
Input_array,TRANSPOSE({1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3}),
uniques,UNIQUE(Input_array),
freq,FREQUENCY(Input_array,uniques),
rows,MAX(freq),
cols,MAX(Input_array),
MAKEARRAY(rows,2*cols,LAMBDA(r,c,LET(cdiv2,QUOTIENT(c+1,2),IF(r>INDEX(freq,cdiv2),"",INDEX(Array_1,r+XMATCH(cdiv2,Input_array)-1,MOD(c+1,2)+1))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach, which uses <kbd>MAKEARRAY()</kbd> function to return the requisite output as desired, a bit late though as I see some good solutions have been posted using <kbd>REDUCE()</kbd> and the <kbd>MAKEARRAY()</kbd> functions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, C2#,
     Φ, UNIQUE(α),
     IFERROR(HSTACK(MAKEARRAY(MAX(MMULT(--(Φ=TOROW(α)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))^0)),
     ROWS(UNIQUE(Φ))*3-1,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(FILTER(A2:B10,α=INT(c/3+0.7)),
     r,MOD(c-1,3)+1))),""),""))
```

---

**Side note:** <kbd>MAKEARRAY()</kbd> would perform slightly better than `recursive` <kbd>REDUCE()</kbd>.

Where <kbd>C2</kbd> `=TOCOL( {1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3})`

---